# WiFi adapter not detected after low battery suspension -- Fedora 29

Tags: fedora, wifi, iwlwifi

I have a Galago Pro running Fedora 29. The computer went into suspension because of low battery. Now, Fedora does not detect the wireless adapter -- meaning the gui manager returns "No WiFi adapter found...".
The adapter was working correctly prior to the suspension.

`rfkill list` shows no hard or soft block.
`lspci` shows:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number a0-a8-cd-ff-ff-df-ff-84
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] Vendor Specific Information: ID=cafe Rev=1 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`ip link` shows:

```
wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether a0:a8:cd:df:ff:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`ip link set wlp3s0 up` has no effect

I have tried a hard (cold) reboot, restarting networking, and restarting network manager.

Comment: How about a cold reboot?

Comment: I have rebooted.

Comment: yeah, but was it a cold or a warm reboot? Have your tried turning it off and on?

Comment: Thanks. It was a cold reboot. I edited my question for clarity.

Comment: Was it recently installed?

Comment: No. Everything has been fine as long as I have had the computer..2 years, maybe??

Comment: Auto updates on our corrupted driver. At most a Wifi switch pressed by accident

Comment: This laptop doesn't have a hardware wireless switch AFAIK. You may have defective hardware. Contact System76.

Answer (score 0):

Run an

```
rfkill list
```

followed by an

```
rfkill unblock x
```

where x is the correct index taken from the list.

Comment: You did see that `rfkill list` shows no blocks, right? I still need to run this?

Comment: Sorry about that.  Read too fast.  I thought it was a power saving feature, disabling the wifi.  Does the keyboard have a function key to enable wifi?

Comment: NP. No keyboard function, nor hardware switch

Comment: It's not in Airplane mode?

Comment: No, not indicated anyway. Shouldn't `rfkill list` show that? I'll double check that bluetooth is working, just to be certain

Comment: bluetooth is working

Comment: And Airplane should be indicated by a led.

Comment: can you check this out?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/760501/driver-for-wireless-7260

Comment: I have not updated the kernel. So, I should not need to blacklist any kernel modules since it was working

Comment: @Roger Creasy - I'll just throw it out there because I find the problem interesting, but the system76 site DOES mention that the keyboard function for airplane mode is Fn + F11.  They also had a lot of things to try for wireless issues.  Apologies if you've already seen it: https://support.system76.com/articles/wireless/

Comment: The power management sounds interesting.

Comment: @bgregs I did see the post on their site. I do appreciate you taking the time to look at my issue.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille The power management does seem like a possible culprit, I will explore

Answer (score 0):

Posting for anyone who comes across this thread in the future.

It turns out that the low battery suspension must have caused some file corruptions. I did a DNF upgrade, and afterwards everything works correctly.

Thanks to all who helped.